# how to delete a value from session with revel

Tags: session, go, revel

Is there a way to delete the value from session witch revel the go web framework?

I have a function for validate captcha for user input, and I set the value of captcha in session, and delete the captcha from session if there nothing to do for client after 1 minute. The code is like:

```
time.AfterFunc(time.Minute, func() {
    delete(this.Session, CSecurityCode)
})
```

But I can still get the old value of captcha , why, and how to fix this?

Anybody who can help me?

Answer (score 0):

The Session value is valid only while processing a client request. i.e. between the time you get the request and the time you respond to that request. Its contents are kept in a cookie on the client side and you'll get a new Session every time the client connects to your server. Thus if you keep it for later use (like the name of your AfterFunc suggests, triggered by a timer?), anything you do with it will be lost on the next client connection.

In order to achieve what you want to do, you'll need to add a "lastSeen" timestamp to the Session. When a request comes in, check Session["lastSeen"], and if it's older than 1 minute, then you can discard CSecurityCode from it.